# In memory iText .PDF is generating with weird characters

Tags: java, pdf, itext, fileoutputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

When I save PDF to file it is working fine but when I generate PDF in memory to save to database it is generating with strange characters.

[wrong PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOHfe.png)

All I need is to generate a PDF to insert into a BLOB type table column, so I have to transform it to byte array first.

In the code, the difference is using FileOutputStream with a file location instead of ByteArrayOutputStream.

It is Java 8, 5.5.13.1 iText version.

I have tried with iText older versions and changing to UTF-8 the file output.

```
public static byte[] xmlToPDF (String xml) {

        // Instanciar el objeto que servirá para retornar al final del método
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Comprobr que ninguno de los parámetros de entrada es NULO ni está vacío
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(xml)) {

            try {

                // Instanciar el documento donde se va a generar el texto
                Document document = new Document();

                // El documento es un .PDF que se gestionará únicamente en memoria (NO se guardará físicamente)
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pdfOutput);

                // Abrir el documento
                document.open();

                document.addTitle("Fichero .XML de la hoja de campo convertido en un .PDF");
                document.addSubject("Generación de .PDF a partir de un .XML");
                document.addKeywords("hoja, campo, xml, pdf, iText");
                document.addAuthor("Agroseguro");
                document.addCreator("Agroseguro");

                // Establecer la fuente del .PDF
                Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 16, BaseColor.BLACK);
                //Font font = FontFactory.getFont(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN.name(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true, 16, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

                // Crear un párrafo con el texto que representa el condenido del fichero
                Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph (new Chunk(xml).getContent(), font);

                // Añadir el párrafo al documento
                document.add(paragraph);

                // Cerrar el documento
                document.close();


            } catch (DocumentException exception) {
                LOGGER.error("Se ha producido un error a la hora de convertir el fichero .XML en un .PDF: " + exception.toString());
            }
        }

        return pdfOutput.toByteArray();

    }
```

The expected PDF is simply a plain text with an XML. The current result is a PDF like this:

```
%PDF-1.4
%ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
3 0 obj
<</Length 860/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
xï¿½ï¿½V]sï¿½6}ï¿½Whï¿½ï¿½>ï¿½ï¿½6$ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
Iï¿½ï¿½)ï¿½%é³°/ï¿½2ï¿½ï¿½
Iï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½,ï¿½fï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Lï¿½ï¿½{t?ï¿½=Wï¿½z
×½ALF,&ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½kï¿½ï¿½Yo{ï¿½ï¿½•]?ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½n?
~lï¿½ï¿½#ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½^JIï¿½`jï¿½UBï¿½>ï¿½
Tï¿½sï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Þ¯ï¿½/Fï¿½ï¿½*~ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½R7\ï¿½\jï¿½
jï¿½a2Vupï¿½4ï¿½ï¿½lWï¿½jï¿½y
tDï¿½Whï¿½ï¿½Ç¦ï¿½ï¿½<ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
ï¿½k(vFï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½|#ï¿½Xï¿½ï¿½;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½qOï¿½ï¿
½ï¿½ï¿½mï¿½b+2ï¿½kC*ï¿½1ï¿½ï¿½.QØ‚ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ß†~
```

and more...

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you opened the PDF in a PDF reader instead of a text editor?

Comment: As previous comment, have you looked at that file in a PDF reader, because that is compressed data which is not human readable.

Comment: Yes I do. I have used the Chrome PDF reader to open de file. I wanted to upload a image whit the PDF OK (with FileOutputStream) Stackoverflow only allowed to upload one, so I decided to upload the PDF KO (with byteArrayOutputStream). I have tried to generate a file in a directory -which works well- and transforming it into byte array and the result is the same.